# GraphQL Apollo Bad request

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to query data from themovieDB with GraphQL and Apollo in a react app.
I'm sending to very similar requests but only one of them seems to work. I've tried separating the queries into separate components but it doesn't help, so it is unlikely that it has to do with the fact that I'm sending multiple queries. "ONE_MOVIE_BY_ID_QUERY" triggers the error "Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400". Here's how I call the queries:

```
const {
        loading : loadingLatest,
        error   : errorLatest,
        data    : latestData,
        refetch : refetchLatest
    } = useQuery(LATEST_MOVIE_QUERY, {
        variables : { movieId: 'latest' }
    });

    const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(ONE_MOVIE_BY_ID_QUERY, {
        variables : { movieId: movieState },
        skip      : !latestData
    });
```

The queries themselves:

```
export const ONE_MOVIE_BY_ID_QUERY = gql`
    query OneMovieByIdQuery($movieId: String!) {
        oneMovieById(movieId: $movieId) {
            id
            adult
            title
            poster_path
            original_language
            original_title
            overview
            release_date
            runtime
            budget
            belongs_to_collection
            imdb_id
            revenue
            tagline
            genres
            production_countries
        }
    }
`;

export const LATEST_MOVIE_QUERY = gql`
    query OneMovieByIdQuery($movieId: String!) {
        oneMovieById(movieId: $movieId) {
            id
        }
    }
`;
```

And finally the GraphQL Schema

```
oneMovieById            : {
            type    : MovieType,
            args    : {
                movieId : { type: GraphQLString }
            },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return axios
                    .get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${args.movieId}?api_key=${myAPIKey}`)
                    .then((res) => res.data);
            }
        }
```

I should point out that the queries seem to work as intended when I try them in GraphiQL and switch between having the variable as "latest" and as a number in a string.

Comment: A 400 status means your query is malformed or otherwise invalid. Check the `error` variable or the actual response from the server in Dev Tools -- this will tell you what's actually wrong with your request.

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience! I'm not sure what to look for in the server response. 
The error variable reads "Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400"

Comment: Open up dev tools in your browser, go to the network tab and inspect the body of the response from the server. You'll see a JSON object with an `errors` array containing additional information about your specific issue.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!! I see the error JSON object now, and indeed it points out some formatting errors in the query that seem in need of adjustments. I'll try to fix that. Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Rearden's answer the mistake I made was that I forgot to include subfields in the query, and that seems to trigger the error. Thanks again for the help!